# 2 divs on top of each other with different widths

Tags: html, overlay

I am looking to create a layout that has 2 containers on top of each other similar to the following website:

www.brightbees.co.uk

What I would like is to have the footer div (see grey bar with links in the footer) as 100% width but then the rest of site on top of the footer to sit within a width of 800px and centred and the last 2 divs to be overlayed on top of the footer div (grey bar).

If somebody could please advise on how i can achieve this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS here.

Answer (score 0):

Use an 800px container to hold all your content divs, then a full width footer positioned relatively higher.

Working example: http://cssdesk.com/eyndc

Comment: thanks for that, just having a look through it. Any reason why the 100% width seems to have a gap on the left hand side? once again thanks for your time.

Comment: thats probably just the example site leaving room for their little arrow button at the top. On a regular page that gap wouldn't be there.